# JWT authentication blocking SockJS handshake when trying to make WebSocket connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, jwt, sockjs

I have a working Spring Boot server with Authentication/Authorization. When trying to open a connection with SockJS it is blocked by my other security measures.

I don't fully understand how the flow of security works in Java yet, but I have an itch that I need to pass the JWT token with the handshake when trying to connect with SockJS. From what I understand this is not possible with SockJS. So I am just wandering what the best approach to getting the socket started with JWT. Also, I know I don't have CSRF enabled so some tips on that would be nice too.

In WebSecurityConfig.java:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors();
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/authenticate", "/login", "/register").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
}
```

In WebSocketConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
            .withSockJS();
    }

}
```

In my Vue app. Trying to connect with JS:

```
      connect() {
            this.socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
            this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
            this.stompClient.connect(
                {
                    token: 'Bearer ' +  localStorage.getItem('user-token')
                },
                frame => {
                this.connected = true;
                console.log(frame);
                this.stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", tick => {
                    console.log(tick);
                    this.received_messages.push(JSON.parse(tick.body).content);
                });
                },
                error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.connected = false;
                })
      },
```

If I remove all the security config I can connect to the WebSocket just fine.

I expect to be able to connect to the WebSocket but right now I am getting a 401 and I cant find a way to authenticate when doing the handshake.

Comment: this may help. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-websockets  looks like you need to do add a config similar to the webSecurityConf

Comment: I tried this, but this seems to secure the sockets after they have been created. My problem is that I can't seem to bypass my own security to go through with the handshake. Am I missing something in this article?

Comment: have you also added items (`.antMatchers( "/secured/**/**","/secured/success", "/secured/socket", "/secured/success").authenticated()`) to the web security? like the example to either `.permitAll()` or another group. your endpoints may differ

Comment: Added this and tried different endpoints. Got rid of a CORS problem but still hitting a 401 from abstract-xhr.js?d8d6:132

Comment: you may be hitting different paths than those specific ones. also can you just add a token to your socket requests.

Comment: That's the problem. From what I've read you can't add headers to the new SockJS request, so it is blocked.

Comment: can you add the paths your hitting to the .permitAll() section of web security config?

Comment: Well yes, that would work. But if I do that I simply bypass the security and everyone can connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Self-awnser

I did a work around by disabling security for the handshake paths in `WebSecurityConfig.java` like this

```java
.antMatchers(
  "/authenticate", 
  "/login", 
  "/register",
  "/secured/chat/**").permitAll()
```

I guess I have to authenticate the user through the socket now, as this makes the socket open to anyone, something I didn't really want.